# Getting description of enum's value without using reflection

Tags: c#, enums

Firstly the reason behind using enums for my case is simply developing a catalog for error codes and I've been using the `Description` attribute to keep the actual error message. I can get the value of the `Description` attribute using reflections but my question is: is there another way to get the value of that attribute without using reflections? For example, there is a `Enum` type in C# so could that type be used instead to get the value of attributes in an enum?

**I know that developing a data model using a class is a better move, enum is an old habit and the reason why I'm insisting on it is because I just wanna know if I can get value of those attributes without reflection.

Comment: No. You can of course map an enum value to a description in a variety of other ways. But if you require the use of a code attribute, I don't believe there is any better way to retrieve it than through reflection.

Comment: A better question is "… without heavyweight reflection code". Reflection is basically unavoidable, but there's probably a way to simplify it to usability.

Answer (score 1):

*Enum is not at all an old habit. It's very useful but to discuss it here would be off-topic...*

Without reflection I can only think about some kind of mapping:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var crazyValue = CrazyEnum.craZyValue1;
        var resonableValue = crazyValue.ToRreasonableString();
    }
}

enum CrazyEnum
{
    craZyValue1,
    CrazYvalUe2
}

static class CrazyEnumMap
{
    private static Dictionary<CrazyEnum, string> resonableStrings = new Dictionary<CrazyEnum, string>
    {
        { CrazyEnum.craZyValue1, "Hallo world!" },
        { CrazyEnum.CrazYvalUe2, "Hallo enum!" }
    };

    public static string ToRreasonableString(this CrazyEnum value)
    {
        return resonableStrings[value];
    }
}
```